# What to use unique_ptr or move semantic?

Tags: c++11

For example I have a class MyClass and two other classes that process the object of MyClass.

Class A - Creates MyClass;

Class B - uses MyClass;

What is the proper way to store and share the MyClass object among A and B. Need to create MyClass with **new** operator and store the pointer in unique_ptr. Or implement **move c-tor**, and create MyClass as stack variable?

Variant 1:

```
class A
{
    public :
    unique_ptr<MyClass> mObj;
};

class B
{
    B( unique_ptr<MyClass> inObj ) : mObj( inObj ) {};
    public :
     unique_ptr<MyClass> mObj;
}
```

Variant 2:

```
class A
{
    public :
     MyClass mObj;
};

class B
{
    B( MyClass&& inObj ) : mObj( inObj ) {};
public :
     MyClass mObj;
};
```

Using:

```
A a;
B( a.mObj );
```

Comment: I don't think there's a right answer to this.  It really depends on whether it makes sense to allocate MyClass on the heap.  And that probably depends on the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both of your examples class `A` can not use myObj after `B` has taken over! This may not be what you what. However if it is intended, than I would recommend using `unique_ptr`. Here it is clear, if and when `A` has lost access to `myObj`. You can test for is by checking if `myObj` is a null pointer.

Comment: Yes, A should not use myObj after pass it to B. Moreover myObj is used even after A is destroyed. In this case, in theory, using move semantic is a good way, or better to use smart pointers?

Comment: In my opinion use `unique_ptr`. By using move semantics you have to take care that the xvalue in `A::myObj` is properly treated.

Answer (score -1):

Neither of proposed solutions are going to work, because both as member variable, and with unique_ptr, you have two independent objects.

If you need to access the same object, either use std::shared_ptr, or use references.

With shared_ptr :

```
class A
{
    public :

    A() : mpObj( new MyClass ) {}


    shared_ptr<MyClass> mpObj;
};

class B
{
public :
    B( shared_ptr<MyClass> inObj ) : mpObj( inObj ) ;

     shared_ptr<MyClass> mpObj;
};
```

Another option is to use references :

```
class A
{
    public :

    A() : mpObj() {}


    MyClass mpObj;
};

class B
{
public :
    B( MyClass& inObj ) : mpObj( inObj ) ;

     MyClass& mpObj;
};
```

What is important is to say who creates and initialize the MyClass object.

Also, read about [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: I'd assumed that the OP was discarding A and transferring the ownership of MyClass to B.  I don't think he needs both classes to use the MyClass object at once.

Comment: @Benj That is how I understood the question. Both classes are using MyClass at once.